Setting up fpush using component protocol with ejabberd
I'm trying to set up push notifications to my custom XMPP iOS client in ejabberd. I saw from this comment on a Github issue that one recommendation is to use an external push service using the component protocol. I chose to use fpush and I'm trying to understand how to configure the component protocol in ejabberd.
As far as I understand I need to setup a new listener and use the ejabberd_service module, which I've done like this:
listen:
-
  port: 1337
  ip: 127.0.0.1
  hosts:
    pushes.mydomain.com:
      password: secret

Then in the fpush config, I set up the component like this:
{
  "component": {
    "componentHostname": "pushes.mydomain.com",
    "componentKey": "secret",
    "serverHostname": "127.0.0.1",
    "serverPort": 1337
  },
  "pushModules": {
    "MyAppName": {
      "type": "apple",
      // etc
    }
}

Is this all I have to do? Because when I start up fpush I get the following error and it's not very helpful:
thread 'main' panicked at /home/ubuntu/fpush/fpush-push/src/lib.rs:64:91:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: PushErrors(PushEndpointTmp)
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

Also the docs for fpush say that the iq stanza has to include the pushModule name. How does ejabberd know how to fill that value in? Is there another piece of config that I'm missing?

OK, at least one answer figured out: I understand now that the iq stanza that contains the pushModule name comes from the client when they activate push notifications for their device. Figured that out from the Monal client source: https://github.com/monal-im/Monal/blob/7ee93f813e4eadf47d5fdf23cfa8e8d641c66cec/Monal/Classes/XMPPIQ.m#L88-L95
